# Hot Add feature + how enable the feature without power off the Linux machine

Tags: vmware-esxi, redhat, virtual-machines, vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter

We have a VM Linux server, where the `hot add` feature is disabled in VCenter.

For now, we can't power off the machine, and the feature is `disable`, so we can't add memory resources to the machine.

So do you have any idea how to enable the `hot add` feature without powering off the Linux redhat machine ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It cannot be done. You'll have to power off the VM at some point, and enable memory (and CPU if you like) hot add.

Answer (score -3):

In the short term, you can add swap to your VM, to give more resources without a reboot.  This is only an interim workaround though, and will not be as fast as real ram.

---

In VMWare?  No this is not possible.  It's not the client OS stopping you, its your virtualisation platform.

---

It is "kind-of" possible in [xcp-ng](https://xcp-ng.org/)  but only up to a specific number that you set before boot.

So a VM can be started with 2 CPUs and 2 GB ram, which can be increased provided you set the maximum numbers before boot.  Eg:

[image: Screenshot of xcp-ng console for CPU properties]

[image: Screenshot of xcp-ng console for memory properties of an instance]

Restrictions

- Maximum memory can be no more than 4x the boot memory.
- CPUs maximum is 32, and if the physical host has less, then the extra are faked which hurts performance
- Your OS has to support hot-add (most linux distros do)

And of course you need to run xcpng, not vmware.

Comment: Your answer is irrelevant, `xcp-ng` is another product based on `Xen`.  The screenshots also are from xcp-ng client. It's perfectly possibly to hot-add memory and CPU on VMware, but it must be set when the VM is powered off. Adding swap is a nice point to mention though.

Comment: @Krackout fair enough - editing to clarify the point.